# in bash: how to execute automatically a command when any commamd is invoked, like by PROMPT_COMMAND, but not awaitng next prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, command-history

Now I use the PROMPT_COMMAND to automatically execute "history -a" to append the history list to HISTFILE.

As suggested in many internet articles.

Additionally I have arranged that after each such action an additional third line is appended to HISTFILE.

I recall:

The first line is always the timestamp: beginning with "#" and followed by 10 digits (seconds since epoch).

The second line is the command.

The third line is now the first line repeated but with suffix

```
tty: /dev/pts/18
```

(or what the pseudoterminal number is).

This works good in normal situations. But just if there is a special need, e.g. in a crash situation, it doeas not work. The third line is then not written, as in many other cases not.

And if the running command is in an endless loop, this is of no help.

I intend to write some code based on the trap "DEBUG".

But perhaps a solution exists.

Please is something known.

Regards

== 19.03.2023 08:10 addendum 1 ::
Since some months in my "we_general_settings" for setting up the shells bash I use

```
HISTIGNORE="#"
```

Therefore I have changed my additional third line which is wrtten by my PROMPT_COMMAND to HISTFILE to begin with a colon ":" ::

```
: #0123456789; tty: dev/pts/18;
```

After this improvement my additional line in HISTFILE is also displayed in the history list.

Regards

== 19.03.2023 08:30 addendum 2 ::
Confusing observations in HISTFILE.

For this report first I have to declare what "<my date_command" is:

```
: # history - s -- "(date "+%F %T %Z %a") - tty: $(tty)"! echo
```

( I always have to input this command twice: first with prefix ": # ", then without -- since tens of years )

And my "<my tail_command" is:

```
tail -n40 /root/.bash_history | /media/... <my script to covert seconds since epoch in normal date_time>
```

Now the tests begin:

0n about 08:46 in shell pts/18 I give:

```
<my date_command>

<my tail_command>
```

The output for the tail of HISTFILE is:

```
#=====2023-03-19_08:46:25=====

: # history -s ...<my date_command>

: #=====2023-03-19_08:46:25=====; tty: /dev/pts/18;

#=====2023-03-19_08:46:31=====

2023-03-19 08:46:31 CET Sun - tty: /dev/pts/18;

: #=====2023-03-19_08:46:31=====; tty: /dev/pts/18;

(end)
```

Now, at 09:15, in shell /dev/pts23 I start utiliy less.

And I go back to shell /dev/pts/18, wait, do nothing.

Now, at 09:25, in /dev/pts/18 I repeat the two commands given previously, i.e.,

```
<my date_command>

<my tail_command>
```

To the output for the tail of HISTFILE following lines were added:

```
#=====2023-03-19_08:46:39=====

tail -n40 ...<my tail_command>;

: #=====2023-03-19_08:46:39=====; tty: /dev/pts/18;

#=====2023-03-19_09:25:27=====

: # history -s ...<my date_command>

: #=====2023-03-19_09:25:27=====; tty: /dev/pts/18;

#=====2023-03-19_09:25:33=====

2023-03-19 09:25:33 CET Sun - tty: /dev/pts/18;

: #=====2023-03-19_09:25:33=====; tty: /dev/pts/18;

(end)
```

Now, at 09:44, in shell /dev/pts/23 I close utiliy less.

And I go back to shell /dev/pts/18, wait, do nothing.

Now, at 09:54, in /dev/pts/18 I repeat the two commands given previously, i.e.,

```
<my date_command>

<my tail_command>
```

To the output for the tail of HISTFILE following lines were added:

```
#=====2023-03-19_09:25:38=====

tail -n40 ...<my tail_command>;

: #=====2023-03-19_09:25:38=====; tty: /dev/pts/18;

#=====2023-03-19_09:15:16=====

less /tmp/WEx1

: #=====2023-03-19_09:45:42=====; tty: /dev/pts/23;

#=====2023-03-19_09:54:49=====

: # history -s ...<my date_command>

: #=====2023-03-19_09:54:49=====; tty: /dev/pts/18;

#=====2023-03-19_09:54:55=====

2023-03-19 09:54:55 CET Sun - tty: /dev/pts/18;

#=====2023-03-19_09:54:55=====; tty: /dev/pts/18;

(end)
```

Notes:

Some oddities I can imagine, e.g.:

When less is invoked the time of this command is registeted by bash. But not appended to HISTFILE because must be waited for the next prompt.

This results that 09:15:16 is in HISTFILE after 09:25:38. -- silly.

Regarding to this: after less was closed, my invented additional HISTFILE line shows 09:45:42.

From what I did, I know that this comes from closing less.

But in general coherencies would not be obvious of one's own accord. An appropriate output is needed.

Etc, etc.

To formulate questions and needs for help would fill a book. Please read self of all oddities of bash and think how to circumvent them.

Regards

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? What exactly is your need? Please don't answer in comments, rather [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774467/edit) the question itself.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a solution _other than 'trap DEBUG'?_